# ERR_INVALID_HANDLE Chrome with IIS7.5

Tags: google-chrome

Since four weeks ago we have received ERR_INVALID_HANDLE in Chrome when accessing an application hosted on II 7.5 (in the production environment). The applications work in other browsers and also in the QA environment - in this environment, the applications run correctly in Chrome as well.

Removing the NEGOTIATE key from web.config is an option, but I'd like to find out why the problem started to happen, the applications always worked correctly even with the NEGOTIATE key, and what puzzles me **is that they run in a QA environment, but not in the production environment**. The problem occurs in any version of Chrome.

This issues occurs accessing a intranet webpage that uses Windows authentication!

*Error message:*

```
Cannot access this site
The web page in wapps ...... may be temporarily unavailable  
or may have been moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_INVALID_HANDLE

Fidler Information

IE x Chrome

IE

HTTP / 1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 341
Content-Type: text / html; Charset = us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-IIS / 7.5
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAGgAaADgAAAAFgomioSBPUb + cKvwAAAAAAAAAAMYAxgBSAAAABgGxHQAAAA9MAE8AQwBBAEwASQBaAEEAXwBDAE8AUgBQAAIAGgBMAE8AQwBBAEwASQBaAEEAXwBDAE8AUgBQAAEAHABTAFIAVgAtAEcAQwBXAEUAQgBQAFIARAAwADIABAAaAGwAbwBjAGEAbABpAHoAYQAuAGMAbwByAHAAAwA4AFMAUgBWAC0ARwBDAFcARQBCAFAAUgBEADAAMgAuAGwAbwBjAGEAbABpAHoAYQAuAGMAbwByAHAABQAaAGwAbwBjAGEAbABpAHoAYQAuAGMAbwByAHAABwAIADhZbSmLQdIBAAAAAA ==
X-Powered-By: ARR / 3.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 18 Nov 2016 11:01:49 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication

Chrome

HTTP / 1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 341
Content-Type: text / html; Charset = us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-IIS / 7.5
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate oYGEMIGBoAMKAQGhCwYJKoZIgvcSAQICom0Ea2BpBgkqhkiG9xIBAgIDAH5aMFigAwIBBaEDAgEepBEYDzIwMTYxMTE4MTEwMTQ5WqUFAgMFa02mAwIBKakPGw1MT0NBTElaQS5DT1JQqhwwGqADAgEBoRMwERsPc3J2LWdjd2VicHJkMDMk
X-Powered-By: ARR / 3.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date Fri, 18 Nov 2016 11:01:47 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```